# error with getting list of apps

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code to get a list of installed apps on the phone but i am getting the following error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to ResolveInfo" for the list "for (ResolveInfo rInfo : **list**)" and also "List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be parameterized" for "**List** list = pm.queryIntentActivities...

```
public class safety extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
            Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Safety extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
            System.out.println("Installed Applications " + rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: when i try it that way all i get is a black screen when ever i run it. any suggestions to why thats happening?

Comment: That's because you have not called setContentView. Your activity doesn't have anything to show. Check your adb logcat. It will print all the applications name.

Comment: Thanks alot... Im not familiar with Eclipse and developing android applications so i didnt no about the logcat and thats the first ive heard of it :)